# Simple C audio library

Tags: c, audio, static-libraries, wav

I'm looking for a simple-ish library for outputting audio. I'd like it to meet these criteria:

- Licensed under LPGL/zlib/MIT or something similar – i'm going to use it in an indie commercial application and i don't have the money for a license.

  Written in C, but C++ is fine.

  Cross-platform (Windows, Linux, maybe OSX)

  Able to read from some sort of audio file (i'd prefer WAV or OGG but i will gladly use less popular formats if need be) in memory (i've seen the use of a memfile struct and user-defined I/O callbacks). I need the file to be in memory because i put all my resources into a .zip archive, and i use [another library](http://code.google.com/p/miniz/) to load those archived files into memory.

  Supports playing multiple sounds at the same time, having a max of 8 or so is ok.

  I'd really like to either have the source code or a static library (MinGW/GCC `lib???.a`), but if nothing else is available i will use a shared library.

I must have come accross two dozen different audio libraries in my search, all of which haven't quite met these criteria...

Comment: You want to things at the same time.

You will need two libraries (correct me if I am wrong), one for decoding (wav is pretty simple, see here http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIFF_WAVE) and bindings for a audio framework to actually play (i.e. send a bytestream to your soundcard).

Comment: Usually the audio framework does that for you, but don't take my word on that, this is implementation dependant and may vary.

Comment: Most libraries that do audio decoding (that I can think of) are file-based, not memory based.

Comment: The WAV format seems simple enough (no compression or anything weird), i could probably decode it myself if i needed to.

Comment: @ldav1s- File-based may be okay if the OP is using Linux.  You can create a ramdisk, put a filesystem on it, and use that for intermediate storage (it's 100% "in memory", but appears to apps like it's a file on a disk).  Would this be an acceptable solution, user1302415?

Comment: I'd need some way to emulate that behavior under Windows... I think it'd be easier to just modify the library's source (if at all possible).

Comment: Have you looked at [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) or [libao](http://www.xiph.org/ao/)?  If so, what needs to they not meet?

Comment: I have looked at both. libao is under the GPL, and PortAudio seems too low-level; it looks like i'd have to write my own mixer, which i would if i knew how.

Comment: Have you looked into SDL and SDL_mixer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend PortAudio + libsndfile. Very popular combo, meets your requirements. Used by many other software applications including audacity.

Comment: I ended up just using WAV, which is a simple enough format to not need libsndfile, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some of the candidates that immediately spring to my mind are:

- [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) (there is a [tutorial](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/C%3aPlaying_a_WAV_Sound_File_With_SDL_mixer) that demonstrates how to play a .wav format sound)
- [libav](http://www.libav.org/)
- [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)
- [libao](http://www.xiph.org/ao/)
- [OpenAL Soft](http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html)
- [Jack Audio](http://jackaudio.org/)

You may have already looked at these and eliminated them, though.  Can you give some more detail about the libraries that you have eliminated from consideration and why?  This will help narrow down our recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) and [SDL_mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/). Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.kekkai.org/roger/sdl/mixer/).
I've used SDL_mixer and it makes it easy to play background sounds or music and play multiple simultaneous sounds without having a need to write your own sound sample mixer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using PortAudio (very low-level, flexible license) and wrote a mixer myself. See [this topic i made on the C++ forums](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/77577/) for some other people's tips on writing a custom mixer. It's not hard at all, really; i'm surprised that there are so many mixer libraries out there. For a breakdown of the WAV format (ready-to-stream raw audio data with a 44-byte header) see [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Comment: Keep in mind that the "header", which is more accurately called a metadata container, may not always be 44 bytes. If you are only dealing with known WAVs, that's fine, but otherwise you need to parse the file correctly and not just assume the chunks are in that order.